# How to determine the bpm (beats per minute) of any song, using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am working on an iPhone app that can determine the bpm (beats per minute) of every song in the iTunes library, and then adjust the songs to 140 bpm (or 70) for the perfect workout tempo.

I have worked on the AVAsset library for capturing the songs from the itunes library, and this part is working fine. Now **I want to capture and then modify the bpm (beats per minute) of that song.**

I would really appreciate, if someone can show me the way that how this can be achieved, and if there is any sample available.

Comment: Do you want your app to put the song back into the library afterwards? If any app would do this to the songs in my library, it would really piss me off.

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer: No I dont want to save it in the library again. After editing, I would just save it in the sandbox

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer: lol..! I guess u have worked on such app.I would really appreciate, if u can help me a bit.

Comment: I haven't worked on any app like that, nor any app that uses sound, except for a beep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the song in AVPLayer. It has setRate functionality to change the tempo of the song.

To read BPM of a song you need to use MPMediaItem.
ex.

```
 MPMediaItem *mediaItem = ...;
 int BPM = [[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute]intValue];
```

*let me know if you need more explanation*

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the BPM being in the metadata for the song? Or does it calculate the BPM if it isn't stored?

Comment: No, it doesn't calculate the BPM. True, that it rely on the metadata of the song.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's running into this problem today... I made a github repo which estimates bpm of a local audio file.

https://github.com/yaizudamashii/BPMDetection-iOS